# Message Highlight when compiling LaTeX document by latexmk

Tags: color, latexmk

It may sound picky, but I'd like to highlight some special messages while compiling LaTeX document by [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/). For example, these are the first few lines of screen messages when I tried to compile a LaTeX document.

```
> latexmk -pvc -pdf doc 
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 10 Nov 2013, version: 4.39.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Viewing pdf
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
  'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 --shell-escape  -recorder  "doc.tex"'
------------
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./doc.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/leqno.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
```

In this example, I'd like to colorize the following two blocks of latexmk execution messages

```
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 --shell-escape  -recorder  "doc.tex"'
------------
```

to distinguish them from the usual LaTeX screen messages.

For colorization, any color will do. For your information, I use bash at Mac OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stealing from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510202/apply-formatting-to-unix-shell

If the script `./zz` outputs the code in your question then (on terminals supporting "ansi" colour codes)

```
RED=`echo -en '\e[31m'`
YELLOW=`echo -en '\e[93m'`
RESET=`echo -en '\e[00m'`
./zz | sed -E "s/(^Running.*)/$RED\1$RESET/g;s/(^Run number.*)/$YELLOW\1$RESET/g"
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use the following trick, which redefines `Run_msg` to reset the color between calls to subprocesses.  In your `latexmkrc`:

```
use Term::ANSIColor;
$color = 'yellow';

print color($color);

{
    no warnings 'redefine';
    sub Run_msg {
        # Same as Run, but give message about my running
        print color('reset'); # NEW LINE-----
        warn_running( "Running '$_[0]'" );
        my $time1 = processing_time();
        my ($pid, $return) = Run($_[0]);
        print color($color); # NEW LINE------
        my $time = processing_time() - $time1;
        push @timings, "'$_[0]': time = $time\n"; 
        return ($pid, $return);
    } #END Run_msg
}
```